# Prove this inequality with $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{3}{15a^2+bc}+\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\ge\frac{4}{ab+bc+cd+da}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ show that
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{3}{15a^2+bc}+\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\ge\dfrac{4}{ab+bc+cd+da}$$
I tried C-S and more, but without success.

I am looking for an human proof, which we can use during competition.

Comment: BW with computer says that your inequality is true.